# How do I fix Blazor MatSelect for int throws an exception

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, matblazor

I am getting this error.  I created a new solution and added this code to the Count page.   This is happening in my larger application but could reproduce it with the skeleton.

I tried taking TValue of the MatSelect without any lock.

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<MatSelect Label="Select" TValue="int" @bind-Value="@Speed">
    <MatOptionString TValue="int" Value="1200">1200 bps</MatOptionString>
    <MatOptionString TValue="int" Value="2400">2400 bps</MatOptionString>
    <MatOptionString TValue="int" Value="4800">4800 bps</MatOptionString>
    <MatOptionString TValue="int" Value="9600">9600 bps</MatOptionString>
    <MatOptionString TValue="int" Value="19200">19,200 bps</MatOptionString>
    <MatOptionString TValue="int" Value="28800">28,800 bps</MatOptionString>
    <MatOptionString TValue="int" Value="38400">38,400 bps</MatOptionString>
    <MatOptionString TValue="int" Value="56000">56,000 bps</MatOptionString>
</MatSelect>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
  private int currentCount = 0;
  public int Speed { get; set; }
  private void IncrementCount()
  {
      currentCount++;
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change MatOptionString to MatOption. They are not string values.